# How to apply params for contextual binding interface resolving in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, interface

I want to resolve context binding with parameters like this:

```
$this->app->when(ParticipantAddedToWaitingList::class)
            ->needs(NotificationParamsResolverInterface::class)
            ->give(function ($event_id, $params = []) {
                return new EventNotificationParamsResolver($event_id, $params);
            });
```

by using this:

```
app()->make(NotificationParamsResolverInterface::class, [123, [1,2,3]]);
```

is this possible or how could I achieve this ?

I know that contextual binding is only resolveable from constructor which does not allows to put params, am I right ?

Is there any workaround for that ?

Answer (score 1):

Contextual binding works when a class takes a given dependency in it's constructor. Laravel will then build the dependency the given way when that class is being newed up.

Using `app()->make()` means there isn't any context - the class isn't being built as a dependency of another, it's just being built up. It's also worth noting that `app()->make()` will no longer take arguments in Laravel 5.4

If you need that class with those given arguments in your application, just new it up yourself - you don't need to use the container.

```
$instance = new EventNotificationParamsResolver(123, [1, 2, 3]);
```

Comment: Seems like feature request. Why context could not been resolved even though using app()->make() method. I do not want to new it by myself because of loose coupling for this class I want to have dynamic control over interface discovery. No arguments for make in 5.4, the are entirely deprecated as well as resolve() ?

Comment: Because `app()->make()` doesn't know from where it's being called. The context feature is all about dependency injection through the container - if you're not using that then this feature isn't for you. Either inject the interface into your controller's constructor or new up the implementation you want to use.

Comment: I was thinking about same funcionality with conrextual binding that DI provides thorugh controller's contrustor.   make() execution context could be resolved right? As class as even method. I think that is called getter Injection which was introduced by Symfony